# how to save values to text file in specific format using matlab

Tags: matlab, format

I have a matrix of values like [150 255 25;400 80 10;240 68 190]. I want to store these values to text file in hexadecimal format such that each value in matrix is represented by 3digit hexa value (12bit). i.e

Decimal               Hexa notation
150 255 25        096  0FF  019
400 80  10    ->  190  050  00A
240 68  190       0F0  044  0BE

I am using like this

```
`fp=fopen('represen.dat','wb');
for i=1:1:x
   for j=1:1:y
       fprintf(fp,"%3x\t",A(i,j));
   end
   fprintf(fp,"\n");
end`
```

It is giving result as
  Decimal               Hexa notation
150 255 25        96   FF   19
400 80  10    ->  190  50   0A
240 68  190       F0   44   BE

help me in this regard..

Answer (score 3):

To insert leading zeros your `fprint` command should look like this:

```
fprintf(fp,"%03x\t",A(i,j));
```