# how to save values to .dat file in specific format using matlab

Tags: matlab, format

I have a matrix of values like [150 255 25;400 80 10;240 68 190]. I want to store these values to text file in hexadecimal format such that each value in matrix is represented by 3digit hexa value (12bit). i.e

```
Decimal               Hexa notation
150 255 25        096  0FF  019
400 80  10    ->  190  050  00A
240 68  190       0F0  044  0BE
```

I am using like this

```
`fp=fopen('represen.dat','wb');
for i=1:1:x
   for j=1:1:y
       fprintf(fp,"%3x\t",A(i,j));
   end
   fprintf(fp,"\n");
end`
```

It is giving result as

```
Decimal               Hexa notation
150 255 25        96   FF   19
400 80  10    ->  190  50   0A
240 68  190       F0   44   BE
```

help me in this regard..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397552/how-to-save-values-to-text-file-in-specific-format-using-matlab

Answer (score 0):

First you have to convert the data to hex:

```
myHexData = dec2hex(myDecimalData)
```

Then you can save it, as explained here and mentioned in the comments by Deve:

[how-to-save-values-to-text-file-in-specific-format-using-matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397552/how-to-save-values-to-text-file-in-specific-format-using-matlab)

Comment: Example: `num2hex(80)` yields `4054000000000000`. That's not the format the OP was asking for.

Comment: ...still the result is `50` instead of `050` as requested by the OP. You will have to use `fprintf` with format string `%03x`.

Comment: gosh, right again... well, isnt this like the question before?

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate

Comment: @Deve does the fprintf-command already convert the decimal data to hex?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36103/discussion-between-deve-and-lucius-domitius-ahenobarbus)

Comment: sorry, but it is not possible for me to chat from here :(

Comment: Ok, no prob. The `x` in the format string `%03x` does the Hex conversion. Just try `sprintf('%x', 120)` at the command line.